# Vue.js + Webpack I get setImmediate.js:80 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am getting the following error when trying to build my bundle, do you know any reason why I might be having it?

somehow function from `node_modules/setimmediate/setimmediate.js`

```js
   function installNextTickImplementation() {
        registerImmediate = function(handle) {
            process.nextTick(function () { runIfPresent(handle); });
        };
    }
```

being replaced to by webpack

```js
    function installNextTickImplementation() {
        registerImmediate = function(handle) {
            {"env": {}}.nextTick(function () { runIfPresent(handle); });
        };
    }
```

which leads to

```
setImmediate.js:80 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Object../node_modules/setimmediate/setImmediate.js (main.js:989)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:790)
    at fn (main.js:101)
    at Object.eval (main.js?5118:54)
    at eval (main.js?5118:63)
    at Object../node_modules/timers-browserify/main.js (main.js:1012)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:790)
    at fn (main.js:101)
    at eval (vue.esm.js?a026:11993)
    at Module../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js (main.js:1024)
```

It happens when I do the following `import Vue from 'vue'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is occurring when updating https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack v1.7.0 to v3.0.0